# JavaScript syntax checking and compression

Tags: javascript, compression, syntax-checking

Do you know a good syntax checker and compressor for JavaScript?

We are currently using JSLINT as syntax checker and YUI for compression. Note we are using the library ExtJS for UI.

Comment: JSLint isn't a syntax checker: "SLint is a static code analysis tool used in software development for checking if JavaScript source code complies with coding rules" (wiki)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about the newly released [Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/)?

It removes dead code, checks syntax, variable references, types, *and warns you* about other common JavaScript pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

Those are top-of-the-line tools that are very good at their respective jobs.  Is there a particular area in which you would like to see improvement?  Otherwise I would say stick with them.

Comment: Better compression without needing to modify our code, better javascript syntax checking (can be done?)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider Google's newly released [Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) and it's [Advanced Compilation options](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3.html).

Comment: It seems it is too much aggressive as it requires some changes in our code in some cases